# Swapping 2D matrix diagonal with a middle line

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, swap

I have a Java 2D array

```
String arraylist numberSeq[][];
```

inside the array list, there is number from 1 to 25,

```
numberSeq[0][0] = 1, [0][1] = 2, [0][2] = 3 , [0][3] = 4 , [0][4] = 5
numberSeq[1][0] = 6, [1][1] = 7, [1][2] = 8 , [1][3] = 9 , [1][4] = 10
......
numberSeq[4][0] = 21,[4][1] = 22,[4][2] = 23, [4][3] = 24, [4][4] = 25
```

So the number will be like

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

After doing a diagonals swap, I wish the output to be like

```
25 20 15 10 5
24 19 14 9  4
23 18 13 8  3
22 17 12 7  2
21 16 11 6  1
```

How can I achieve that when I can only declare one local variable?

If one local variable is not achievable, how much is the minimum number of local variables I need?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried some of the method but those method does not fit any of the requirements , so I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Its better if you share what you've tried and what you think is possible way to look into for your solution.

Comment: Check [XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by making another teo dimensional array, iterating through your first in the right order and post it to a new one.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int dimension = 5;

        int[][] numberSeq = new int[dimension][dimension];

        numberSeq[0][0] = 1; numberSeq[0][1] = 2;numberSeq[0][2] = 3;numberSeq[0][3] = 4;numberSeq[0][4] = 5;
        numberSeq[1][0] = 6; numberSeq[1][1] = 7;numberSeq[1][2] = 8;numberSeq[1][3] = 9;numberSeq[1][4] = 10;
        numberSeq[2][0] = 11;numberSeq[2][1] = 12;numberSeq[2][2] = 13;numberSeq[2][3] = 14;numberSeq[2][4] = 15;
        numberSeq[3][0] = 16;numberSeq[3][1] = 17;numberSeq[3][2] = 18;numberSeq[3][3] = 19;numberSeq[3][4] = 20;
        numberSeq[4][0] = 21;numberSeq[4][1] = 22;numberSeq[4][2] = 23;numberSeq[4][3] = 24;numberSeq[4][4] = 25;

        int[][] flippedSeq = new int[dimension][dimension];

        // This is the flipping part
        for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
            {
                flippedSeq[i][j] = numberSeq[dimension-1-j][dimension-1-i];
            }
        }

        PrintMatrix(numberSeq);
        System.out.println();
        PrintMatrix(flippedSeq);


    }

    public static void PrintMatrix(int[][] mat)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope thats what you meant by "1 local variable".

Output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 

25 20 15 10 5 
24 19 14 9 4 
23 18 13 8 3 
22 17 12 7 2 
21 16 11 6 1
```

Comment: Yes , exactly , this is the things I've been looking for , thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This should help. so yes, a swap with a single local variable is possible.

```
public swapDiagonally(int[][] mtx) {
  for(int i = 0 ;i< mtx.length; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < mtx[0].length - i; j++){ 
        int temp = mtx[i][j];
        mtx[j][i]; = mtx[mtx.length-1-i][mtx[0].length-1-j];
        mtx[mtx.length-1-i][mtx[0].length-1-j] = temp;
     }
  } 
}
```

I am essentially traversing 'total rows - N' for every Nth column, thus, helping me travers this structure:

```
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3
 1 2
 1
```

for a 4x4 array!!!

Answer (score 0):

the following loop will do the diagonal swap as in your question:

```
    int n=5;
    int[][] newmat = new int[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            newmat[(n-1) - j][(n-1)- i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
```